# My serializer that returns a 0 for Null value is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serializer that returns the value 0 instead of `Null` when API data is requested.

```
class MyIntegerField(serializers.IntegerField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return 0
        return super(MyIntegerField, self).to_representation(value)

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_count = MyIntegerField(initial=0)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (...,
                 'post_count',
                  ...)
```

model.py:

```
post_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

If a user has no posts, then I would like to return the value 0, instead of Null.

What is the issue with my current serializer? I think the field that's inputted is still pulling from my model field, and not the new serializer function.

Currently I'm still receiving a Null when user requests data.

Comment: I think you are looking fo the `.to_internal_value(self, data)` method instead of the `to_representation(self, value)` method.

Comment: Willem, just tried your method recommendation for the function and return. Not getting any errors but still getting a `Null` in the return data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) instead

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (...,
                 'post_count',
                  ...)
    def get_post_count(self, obj):
        if obj.post_count:
            return obj.post_count
        return 0
```

Comment: I did not know `SerializerMethodField()` existed :) , you just made my life a lot easier from here on out.

Comment: @Dre Don't forget that this is a read-only field and avoid using too much in the serializer. Because it will reduce the performance a bit ^^

Comment: Curious to know why it will slow performance?

Comment: For your case, we should use it. The execution time of SerializerMethodField related to the execution time of the block of code in the `get_post_count` method.